# Why 'xauth list' doesn't show a TCP socket after ssh-X

Tags: ssh, xforwarding, xauth

I have a very little experience in linux, but these days, I was trying to understand a bit more about ssh and X forwarding. I use an SBC (orange pi zero 2) as a home server under debian.

I usually `ssh -X` to my server from mobaXterm on a windows 11 PC.
Everything runs smoothly and I have no problem opening a window on my local machine (gvim for instance).

However I was just curious about one thing: my `DISPLAY` variable is set to `localhost:10` (which I expected), but `xauth list` only show an entry for `myserver/unix:10`, which is a unix socket, as far as I understand.

So I was wondering why (and, above all, if) X authentication is actually working...

Most of my knowledge on these things com from [this very interesting page](https://goteleport.com/blog/x11-forwarding/)
and I assumed `xauth list` would have shown an entry for my `DISPLAY` variable (a TCP socket).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The libxcb low-level X11 client library has a special case for displays at "loopback" addresses – instead of looking up an Xauthority entry for the address, it will automatically look for a 'FamilyLocal' authentication entry (i.e. the type used for Unix sockets) for the system's own hostname. In other words, all display addresses that resolve to `127.0.0.1` or `::1` (but not to, say, 127.0.0.2) will be treated as the "myserver/unix" entry.